# Is there a way to programmatically confirm that a python package version satisfies a requirements specifier?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, requirements.txt

I am trying to find whether there is a way to take an installed package and version and check whether it satisfies a requirements spec.

For example, if I have the package pip==20.0.2, I want the program to do the following:

```
CheckReqSpec("pip==20.0.2", "pip>=19.0.0")  -> True
CheckReqSpec("pip==20.0.2", "pip<=20.1")    -> True
CheckReqSpec("pip==20.0.2", "pip~=20.0.0")  -> True
CheckReqSpec("pip==20.0.2", "pip>20.0.2")   -> False
```

I found that pkg_resources.extern.packaging has version.parse, which is useful for comparing different versions greater than or less than, but requirement specs can be very complex, and there are operators like ~= that are not standard mathematical operators.

The setuptools docs has this example:

```
PickyThing<1.6,>1.9,!=1.9.6,<2.0a0,==2.4c1
```

Is there an existing way to do this check, or an easy way to make my own?

edit:
The ~= in particular is difficult, especially if the specs are input as a variable. * in the version requirement is also hard to figure out, since

```
 version.parse("20.0.*") == version.parse("20.0.1") # False
 version.parse("20.0.*") < version.parse("20.0.0")  # True 
 version.parse("20.0.*") < version.parse("20.1.1")  # True 
 version.parse("20.0.*") >= version.parse("20.0.0") # False
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `pkg_resources` (from setuptools) as an API is now deprecated, and will cause warnings at import time:

```
$ python3 -W always -c 'from pkg_resources import Requirement'
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
```

Instead, we can parse a requirement using [`packaging`](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) (which `pkg_resources` was using internally anyway). Check requirement name is matching with an equality comparison, and check requirement version is within a specifier set using `in`:

```
>>> from packaging.requirements import Requirement
>>> req = Requirement("pip~=20.0.0")
>>> pin = "pip==20.0.2"
>>> name, version = pin.split("==")
>>> name == req.name and version in req.specifier
True
```

Post releases work. Pre-releases have to be opted in for explicitly.

```
>>> "20.0.0post1" in req.specifier
True
>>> req.specifier.contains("20.0.1b3")
False
>>> req.specifier.contains("20.0.1b3", prereleases=True)
True
```

*Note*: a top-level `packaging` installation may be at a different version than the packaging version which [pip vendors](https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/23.2.1/src/pip/_vendor/packaging) and uses internally. If you need to *guarantee* the packaging APIs are matching pip's behavior exactly, you could import the `Requirement` type from pip's vendored subpackage directly:

```
from pip._vendor.packaging.requirements import Requirement
```

Or, if importing from a private submodule scares you, then install packaging at top-level to the exact same version which your pip version is currently vendoring. Check your pip version (with `pip --version`) and then check the corresponding packaging version which pip vendors. For example, if your pip version is 23.2.1 you may check in:

https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/23.2.1/src/pip/_vendor/vendor.txt

Here you will see that pip==23.2.1 vendors an older version at packaging==21.3.

Comment: Oh, this may be it! I notice that it doesn't quite handle prerelease versions/post release versions like version.parse does, so I may use this just for * and ~=. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FutureGadget Post-releases: it does handle them. No change needed. Pre-releases: It does handle them, but they are disallowed by default (as pip won't use them by default). If you want to include prereleases, you can use `req.specifier.contains(v, prereleases=True)`.

Comment: For completeness, might be worth making explicit: **1.** the import package `pkg_resources` is part of the distribution package [`setuptools`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/). **2.** the underlying library vendored in `pkg_resouces` (as well as `setuptools`) is [`packaging`](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [`packaging`](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/), which could be used like the following:

```
>>> import packaging.requirements
>>> import packaging.version
>>> packaging.version.parse('20.0.2') in packaging.requirements.Requirement('pip>=19.0.0').specifier
True
>>> packaging.version.parse('20.0.2') in packaging.requirements.Requirement('pip~=20.0').specifier
True
>>> packaging.requirements.Requirement('pip==20.0.*').specifier.contains('20.0.2')
True
>>> packaging.requirements.Requirement('pip==20.0.*').specifier.contains('21')
False
>>> packaging.requirements.Requirement('PickyThing<1.6,>1.9,!=1.9.6,<2.0a0,==2.4c1').specifier
<SpecifierSet('!=1.9.6,<1.6,<2.0a0,==2.4c1,>1.9')>
```

Comment: That's actually the same approach as my answer: both `pip` and `pkg_resources` vendors packaging's `SpecifierSet` for this functionality. The difference is that setuptools should usually be available already in site-packages, since it comes installed with ensurepip and with venv, but `packaging` would have to be installed separately to be available as a top-level import like this. And if you install it separately, you may get a more recent release, so you're not guaranteed to get the same code that pip/setuptools is actually using (whether that is good or bad depends on the use-case, I guess).

Comment: @wim absolutely, I upvoted your answer (as well as the other one). Just a slightly different approach I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`packaging`](https://github.com/pypa/packaging)?

```py
from packaging import version

version.parse("20.0.2") > version.parse("19.0.0")   # True
version.parse("20.0.2") <= version.parse("20.1")    # True
version.parse("20.0.2") >= version.parse("20.0.0")  # True
version.parse("20.0.2") > version.parse("20.0.2")   # False
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the pkg_resources.extern.packaging version that I mentioned - it works for the most comparisons like <, >, !=, etc but it doesn't handle ~=.

It would be best if there's a specific method built in because I am not sure what all the possible requirement specs are...

Comment: With some parsing you should (theoretically) be able to simulare `~=` as described in [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release).

Comment: I just added a small edit - the * character in the requirement spec is tough to compare with. It's a little strange with version.parse:
`version.parse("20.0.*") != version.parse("20.0.1")`  # True
`version.parse("20.0.*") < version.parse("20.0.0")`   # True
`version.parse("20.0.*") >= version.parse("20.0.0")` # False

And unfortunately it's part of the PEP440 definition of ~=.

Comment: This will get unwieldy pretty quickly.  How would you use this method for an example like `"PickyThing<1.6,>1.9,!=1.9.6,<2.0a0,==2.4c1"`?

Comment: packaging is not builtin